# Hibernate : Projection to boolean on a String property

Tags: hibernate, criteria, projection, hibernate-criteria, resulttransformer

I use a Criteria request using a Projections list to return a custom DTO. For now I have two projections on properties :

```
criteria.setProjection(
   Projections.projectionList
      .add(Projections.property("Employee.id"), "id")
      .add(Projections.property("Employee.name"), "name"))
   .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(EmployeeDto.class));
```

In my EmployeeDto, i have a boolean property "hasPicture". This information is a Nullable String column (the name if the picture actually) on my Employee table.

I do not care about the name itself, I would like to add a new projection that does the following:

PictureName != null  --> dto.hasPicture = true

PictureName == null --> dto.hasPicture = false

**Is that possible? How?**

Comment: Thks Mr Stef. I've already made this workaround, it works fine of course. But my question is more to know if there is a way to do that directly in the criteria query, by default. So, can I conclure there is no such a thing with Hivernage? I take note about your 2nd solution though. ;)

Comment: Hivernage = Hibernate (ahah damned french spell check!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do this check within your hasPicture function.

```
  public Boolean hasPicuture(){
     if (this.picture == null)
      return false 
    return this.picture
     }
```

Another way would be to write your own Boolean type and use it in your mappings.